# how to answer for the question non-ecr category

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, ecr

I'm applying for my passport. I passed 10th standard. Now I'm studying btech (bachelor's at a technical university) 2nd year. I'm 19 years old. What should I answer for the question "ARE YOU ELIGIBLE FOR NON-ECR CATEGORY"? The choices are either yes or no.

Comment: For which country?

Comment: @Willeke: Apparently "ECR" is a category of Indian passports whose holders are not allowed to leave the country without applying for specific government permission in advance. (Shades of East Germany! ...) But let's see what the OP replies.

Answer (score 2):

The list of documents required to allow non-ECR is [here](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/onlineHtml/NonEcrDocuments.html).

They include (I'm not going to reproduce the entire list):

```
Educational matriculation (passing 10th grade counts)
Evidence that you're a tax-payer
Gazetted government servants (and relatives)
Anyone over 50 or under 18
Professional degree holders
Others (see the website)
```